# Invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' in switch statement

Tags: c++

I am in the process of trying to make a switch statement that takes the first character of a char array and capitalises it. I'm still very much a beginner so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong! The error I'm getting is this:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
    return "A";
```

And this is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char capitalize(char x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
        case a:
            return "A";
            break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char name[50];

    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    cin.getline(name, 49);
    cout << "Hello there, " << name << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sorry if this seems like a stupid question.

Comment: Change it to `return 'A';` because `"A"` is a string litteral, `'A'` is a character litteral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `return "A";` with `return 'A';`

- Type of `'A'` — `char`, it’s a single ASCII character
- Type of `"B"` — `const char *`, it’s a NULL-terminated ASCII string
- Type of `L'C'` — `wchar_t`, it’s a single Unicode character
- Type of `L"D"` — `const wchar_t*`, it’s a NULL-terminated Unicode string

Comment: This fixed it, thanks. Why can't I use speech marks in this scenario? Is it better practice to always use apostrophes?

Comment: The stuff about ASCII vs. Unicode is misleading. UTF-8 fits nicely into `char` sequences.

Comment: @chris, unlike UCS-2, C runtime has no support for UTF8 strings�